How to disable particular audio jack in debian?
I have recently dual booted Windows and Debian based Kali Linux. I have a faulty front panel audio jack. This causes the speakers to instantly disconnect and reconnect over and over again, which increases CPU uses. The problem occurs even if the front panel jacks are not connected into. Even if I disconnect them from the motherboard, the problem persists. I could get around this problem on windows using Realtek HD audio manager which could disable the detection of front panel jacks on the software level. This solved the problem, the audio was no longer disconnecting and reconnecting every other second now.
This issue is also present on Linux and the instant disconnect and reconnect causes high CPU uses. But I can't find a similar functionality on Linux to disable front panel jacks. Pulse audio has an option in configuration for "Off" but that entirely disables the sound. How do I completely disable the detection of just the front panel jacks?
Please don't suggest me to buy a new motherboard, although the problem is with the motherboard itself.

Of note, Kali isn't Debian.

@ChanganAuto I never said it was. I just mentioned it to be debian based

In the actual question yes, you mentioned it. But NOT in the title.

I wanted it to be more generic, nevermind :)

If the mainboard uses HD-Audio, use hdajackretask from alsa-tools-gui.

Thank you very much. It worked like a charm! I had to disable pipewire and wireplumber that were using the sound device as mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261182/how-to-make-hdajackretask-work-in-ubuntu-20-04 first. After system reboot, I simply restarted pulseaudio daemon and I was good to go
